# Trying getting json from online api.fixer.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a converter EUR-USD using ajax requests and jquery and getting values from an online API:

```
 http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=EUR
```

Now I only try to see if the call is done and it returns succesfully the JSON from the link. My code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#idButton").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=EUR",
       data: {},
       succes: function(result) {
         data = JSON.parse(result);
         //$("#idUsd").val();
         console.log(data);

       },
       error: console.log("dsfhg")
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #808080;
}
.myEuro {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#idButton {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background-color: #483D8B;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.classTF {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demo 2</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <form class="myForm" id="form">

    <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="Euro/s" class="classTF">

    <input type="text" name="to" placeholder="USD" class="classTF" id="idUsd">
    <button type="submit" name="button" id="idButton">Convert into USD</button>


  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In my console it's printed

```
 dsfhg
```

meaning I got an error. But I don't know what I did wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have a typo in `success`

Comment: Now I receive Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Check my answer with a fiddle. You don't need to parse response.

Comment: That error is coming from `JSON.parse`, meaning the thing you are parsing is not a valid JSON string. as @vp_arth mentioned, you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=EUR",
   data: {},
   success: function(result) { // success mispelled
     console.log(result); // jQuery was autoparse json response
   },
   error: function(x, e) { console.log(e); } // must be function, not implicit call
 });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ekye428/1/)

Comment: now I added a new line after console.log(result):$("#idUsd").val(parseInt(data['rates']['USD']) * parseInt($("#idEur").val()));    and it gives the error: uncaught referenceerror:data is not defined.

Comment: `data is not defined` means you have not `data` variable. Use `result.rates.USD`

Answer (score 1):

> In my console it's printed `dsfhg` meaning I got an error. But I don't know what I did wrong.

You are not specifying your error handler properly. What you are doing
is giving it a **result of a function execution**, not a function
on its own. Here's what's happening:

```
$.ajax({
  // ... rest of the code
  error: console.log("dsfhg")
});
```

When this code gets called, it will call `console.log` first, because a function is called whenever the JS Engine encounters something like `f()` -> *notice the `()`*.

Calling `console.log` returns `undefined`, and then that's what the value of `error` becomes in the object you pass to ajax.

In other words, what you are passing to ajax is:

```
$.ajax({
  // ... rest of the code
  error: undefined // with console.log('dsfhg') called to return this `undefined`
});
```

This means that, whether you receive the data or not, when you click your button, `console.log('dsfhg')` is **always called** because you call it before you pass in stuff to ajax, and this means you will not have an error handler.

What you probably intended to pass as an error handler is something like:

```
$.ajax({
  // ... rest of the code
  error: function() { 
    console.log("dsfhg"); 
  }
});
```

---

Now if you are experiencing an error, you might want to log the data passed into the error handler to help you further identify what is happening:

```
$.ajax({
  // ... rest of the code
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    console.log(errorThrown); 
  }
});
```

And of course, whenever not sure, [research how to do stuff](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20ajax%20error).

---

Also, as pointed out in the comments by **vp_arth**, you misspelled `success` as `succes`, which won't work the way you need it to meaning it won't be called when the ajax call is successful. You would need this:

```
$.ajax({
  // ... rest of the code
  success: // ... not succes
});
```

Comment: I changed it and the same thing is printed.

Comment: Ok, so how to resolve it? To go on the successful part

Comment: That is a very vague question, I cannot solve an error because I don't know what the error is, how it's happening etc, you can look at my edits for some suggestions but you must research your exact error yourself. It is not fair for me to do all the work :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such code to converter EUR-USD using Ajax requests and JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#convert').on('click',function () {


    let val = $('#from_currency').val();
    let currency = $('#to_currency').val();

    $.ajax({url : uri}).then(function (res) {

        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.rates);
        console.log('res.rates.'+currency);

        if (val.trim() !== '') {

            $('#result').val(val * res.rates.USD);
        }


    });

});
```

});